# Extension on nested generic types

Tags: swift, generics

I have a simple Result type:

```
enum Result<ValueType> {
    case success(ValueType)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

I want to create a function on arrays of Results, and arrays of optional Results, to combine all results into one. However, I am struggling mightily to figure out a way to express this. This is what I want to do:

```
extension Array<Optional<Result<ValueType>>> {
    func combined() -> Result<[ValueType]>? {
        var values: [ValueType] = []
        for result in self {
            switch result {
                case .success(let value)?:
                    values.append(value)
                case .failure(let error)?:
                    return .failure(error)
                case .none:
                    return nil
            }
        }
        return .success(values)
    }
}
```

This obviously does not compile. But is there a way to actually express this?

Comment: Don't forget to `values.reserveCapacity`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply make the `combined` function generic with a generic type constraint instead of making the whole extension generic.

```
extension Array {
    func combined<ValueType>() -> Result<[ValueType]>? where Array.Element == Optional<Result<ValueType>> {
        var values: [ValueType] = []
        for result in self {
            switch result {
            case .success(let value)?:
                values.append(value)
            case .failure(let error)?:
                return .failure(error)
            case .none:
                return nil
            }
        }
        return .success(values)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
let optionalResults: [Result<Int>?] = [Result.success(1),Result.success(2)]
optionalResults.combined() //success([1,2])
let strings = ["a","b"]
strings.combined() //doesn't compile
let ints = [1,2]
ints.combined() //doesn't compile
```

Comment: Nice! This works perfectly.

That was probably the one way around I had not tried to do it, sigh.